# How to make Navbar links work active mode and when visited mode

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navbar, anchor

I have an issue with the CSS functionality of the links in NavBar, only the #hover style seems to be working. what could be the error? I tried to debug but couldn't. Can any one help please?

CSS

```css
.header a:visited {
  background: rgb(241, 195, 163);
}

.header a:hover {
  background: rgb(61, 34, 34);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  color: white;
}

.header a:active {
  background: white;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <img src="IMAGES/20190711_132415.png" alt="logo" />
  <a class="active" href="contact.html">Contacto</a>
  <a href="#los clientes">Clientes</a>
  <a href="products.html">Productos</a>
  <a href="ourRituals.html">Rituales</a>
  <a href="landingPage.html">Santuario</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't try .header .active css class to change background color for the active nav link.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Maybe the white background you are setting, is why you can't see the effect .

Comment: @faiz-e I dnt think it should be the case because the background of the navbar is a colourful image so white backgroud should be visible. I tried others colours too but to no avail